# how to map multiple values in c++?

Tags: c++

current code

```
std::map<std::string,int> m;
...
m.insert(std::pair<std::string,int>(text,lineno));
...
std::cout<<"key: "<<iter->first<<"lineno: "<<iter->second<<std::endl;
```

how to save mutiple values in same key?

Comment: Please don't tag C++ questions with C. They're different languages.

Comment: Map your key to a vector in which you can store multiple values.

Comment: If multiple values are of the same type ```T```, just use ```std::map<std::string,std::vector<T>>```.

Comment: Or use a [`std::multimap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap). The clue is in the name.

Comment: Vectors? Arrays? Structures/classes? Tuples? There are many ways to collect "multiple values" into a single entity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To sum up the comments of others, here's an answer.

Say you have some type `T` and would like to map a `std::string` to multiple values of that type. The easiest way to do this, when you don't know how many multiple values you need to map to, is to use an `std::vector <T>`. If you do know how many multiple values you're going to be dealing with for each key, you could map to an `std::array <T>`.

```cpp
std::map <std::string, std::vector <int>> map;
map ["A"].push_back(10);
map ["B"].push_back(20);
map ["A"].push_back(42);
```

You could use a `std::multimap <std::string, int>` similarly if you're dealing with what I showed above.

```cpp
std::multimap <std::string, int> map;
map.insert({"A", 10});
map.insert({"B", 20});
map.insert({"A", 42});
```

If you would like to map one key to multiple values that are to hold information of different types, you could use a `std::map <std::string, std::vector <std::tuple <int, std::string, std::pair <int, int>>>> // ...etc.`.

You could use a vector of some structure data type too as a substitute to tuples in the above example.

Comment: I wrote the code after hearing your answer, but there is an error. Can you help me?                                               std::map<std::string,std::vector<int>> m; m[yytext].push_back(lineno); std::map<std::string,std::vector<int>>::iterator iter; for (iter=m.begin(); iter!=m.end(); iter++){ std::cout<<iter->first<<":"<<*iter<<std::endl;}    how cout the vector? the error is *iter

Comment: @pythonyyyy That's because *iter has the type `std::pair <std::string, std::vector <int>>`. You can't directly cout that without using a bunch of operator overloads. What you want to do is basically iterate over iter->second. Something like: `for (int it : iter->second){ }`. iter->second is what has the type `std::vector <int>` and you can iterate through it like you'd normally do through a vector.

Answer (score 2):

```
std::map<std::string,int> m;
```

By declaring this (the above) you have instantiated map which the keys of this `map` (m) of type `string` and the values are of type `int`.

In `C++` you can declare a `map` with keys and values pairs, from any type, what ever you like/need, so the answer would be, `vector` or **depends** on what do you want to achieve from this `Data Structure`.

here is ilustration with vector:

```
std::map<std::string,std::vector<int>> my_map;
```

here is ilustration with values of type map:

```
std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, int>> my_map;
```

**Note**

If you are working with `c++` version or standard compiler less that `c++11`, you need to add space between the adjacent right angle brackets, like so:

```
std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, int> > my_map;
```

Comment: I wrote the code after hearing your answer, but there is an error. Can you help me? std::map<std::string,std::vector<int>> m; m[yytext].push_back(lineno); std::map<std::string,std::vector<int>>::iterator iter; for (iter=m.begin(); iter!=m.end(); iter++){ std::cout<<iter->first<<":"<<*iter<<std::endl;} how cout the vector? the error is *iter –